# In how many ways can four men and four women form a circle if the men and women alternate positions?

Tags: combinatorics

> Four men and four women are forming a circle for a folk dance. In how many ways can this be done if we require that the men and women alternate positions?

My attempt was to square $24$ for total possibilities $= 576$. Then I tried to find out how many possibilities to subtract to find the answer. I got nowhere. I did find a couple of equations concerning circles and rings but they seemed contradictory:

1. The number of ways $n$ distinct objects can be arranged in a circle is $(n-1)!$.
2. The number of ways $n$ distinct beads (with $n\geq 3$) can be placed on a necklace is $(n-1)!/2$.

I don't see the difference.

Thank you for any insight you can give me.

T. Grode

Comment: Well, I can flip a key ring over, so reversing the order isn't distinct ( so divide by two).  I don't think you want to flip the dance floor over and consider the dancing arrangement unchanged.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar An answer without an explanation is not helpful.  An **incorrect** answer without explanation, even moreso.  It is downright harmful.

Comment: Let me check my mistake

Comment: @ArchisWelankar It is a good idea to check your formulae against extreme cases to make sure that they work correctly.  One should expect that with one man and one woman, there is only one way that they can stand in a circle.  Make sure that your proposed formula does not give the answer of $2$.  Further, with two men and two women, the only question is from one of the men's perspective which of the two women is on his right.  There are only two arrangements in that case.

Comment: Ya now it's clear thanks sir.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar you can calculate available arrangements to 3!*4! / 2

Comment: @agawa001 that is also incorrect.  I wonder if people even read my answers before posting comments like these some times

Comment: @Agawa001 it looks like your proposed formula is for $n$ men and $n$ women, that the number of arrangements is $(n-1)!n!/2$.  What happens when $n=1$?  Are you saying there is $\frac{1}{2}$ way to arrange the two people in a circle on the dance floor.  Can that even make sense?!

Comment: @ T.Grode I've edited from talking about key-rings to necklaces instead.  [Combinatorial Necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) are what the objects you refer to are commonly called (and are not what the problem asks for).  I dislike the analogy of key rings because many common keys one can tell up from down based on the direction of the teeth of the key in the case that the keys have teeth only on one side (as is common).  If one were to consider the orientation of the teeth important, you would get an answer different than both of those given.

Comment: The edits to my question are acceptable and make sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply multiplication principle for the following steps:

- Arrange the men in a circle.  Have the men leave a bit of extra space inbetween themselves.
- Once the previous step is completed, place a woman into each empty space.

> The first step can be completed in $3!$ ways.  The second step can be completed in $4!$ ways.  Applying multiplication principle, there are then $3!\cdot 4!$ arrangements.

We can generalize this to $n$ men and $n$ women.

> There will be $(n-1)!$ ways to do the first step.  There will be $n!$ ways to do the second step.  There will then be $(n-1)!\cdot n!$ total number of arrangements.

---

In counting how many options there are to complete the first step, we may recognize that we may divide by symmetry or we can come up with a more clever way of describing how to accomplish the first step without overcounting.  For example:

- Set the man whose name appears first in alphabetical order on the dancefloor, it matters not where.
- Pick one of the remaining men to stand in clockwise position to the first man.
- Pick another of the remaining men to stand in the next available position clockwise.
- Repeat this process until all men are placed.

Comment: that answer in incomplete, you must divide by 2 for eliminating redundancy of the other waywise order wich matches an arbitrary ordering, setting an individu m/f as an axis

Comment: @Agawa001 no you don't.

Comment: i am sorry to say you [must](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5AkUv.png)

Comment: @agawa001 the two arrangements in your image are different.  People standing in a circle are not necklaces.  One arrangement obtained from another via rotations are considered the same.  One obtained from another via a reflection are different.  Imagine if we are doing a circular conga line traveling clockwise.  If the person clockwise from me walks too fast it is of no discomfort to me.  However if the arrangement were reflected, they would be stepping on my heels.  The experiences are different, hence the arrangements are different.

Comment: @jm conga is done inline but here is a group circle dance as an irish or balkan dance

Comment: @agawa001 that is besides the point.  The point is the only symmetries that matter are rotation.  Not reflection.  If you wish to get really technical, you could approach via burnsides lemma which is overkill for this problem.  If the stepping on each other's feet analogy didn't work for you, then imagine the dance calls for placing an arm in the shoulder to the person to your right.  Reflections change who it is you put your hand on.

Comment: @jm i m sorry to flood your posts with comments but do we deal with combinatorics as humans with hands and shoulders ? no, we either consider the particles as distinct, or not distinct, here only gender matters, not hands nor shoulders neither stepping on feet of eachother

Comment: @agawa001 when one says "arrange objects in a circle" it implies that rotations are considered the same.  It does **not** imply that reflections are the same.  You are correct that it doesn't matter about if the people have hands and shoulders, i was making an analogy to try to convince you that reflections do not preserve the arrangement.  If we were told that no one at the dance can distinguish right from left, then perhaps reflections can be considered as keeping things "the same."  Since it is not mentioned, it is assumed that right is different from left.

Comment: @agawa001 therein lies the difference between asking for how many **circular arrangements** there are and how many **necklaces** there are.   Circular arrangements, only rotations keep things the same.  Necklaces, rotations **or** reflections will keep things the same.  In a circular arrangement of three objects, 123 is the same as 231 and 312, but is not the same as 132

Comment: i based my argument on the fact that op sheds light on the division part, so i was trying to point it out how division matters, since refelectional symmetry counts as independent arrangement, i see no point why op used division ??

Comment: anyways sorry my point of view got dropped, we may remove our comments unless you see a good aim for it to be read by users.

Comment: @agawa001 the division is for **necklaces**, not for circular arrangements.  The op did not use division for this problem.  He stated the general formulae for circular permutations and the general formula for necklaces, but was confused which is applicable here and why they are different.  They are different as I have tried explaining to you because necklaces can be flipped upside down.   Circular arrangements of people cannot.